# splitting a string in to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tokenize

I have a string in the form,

`var k= '<html><div id="test">it is interesting</div></html>'`,

I am trying to convert this in to an array of form

```
<html>
<div id="test">
it
is
interesting
</div>
</html>
```

I am using Javascript to perform this task. I could use the split function a detect the space in between words to split the string, but how do I split the HTML tag.

Comment: Could you use JQuery on that string to create an object tree of the HTML elements?

Comment: Why are you trying to do what you are describing here..?

Comment: Splitting at the space wouldn't actually work, as there is a space here: `<div id=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var k='<html><div id="test">it is interesting</div></html>';
var a=k.match(/(<.+?>)|([^ ]+?(?=[ <]))/g);
console.log(a); // ["<html>", "<div id="test">", "it", "is", "interesting", "</div>", "</html>"]
```

**Update:** If your string can contain substring *`"<>"`* (not valid in HTML) then try to use regular expression with minor changes: `/(<.*?>)|([^ ]+?(?=[ <]))/g`

**Update:** If you need to interpret `\n\r\t` simbols (new line, carriage return, tab) as space try to use next regular expression: `/(<.*?>)|(\S+?(?=[\s<]))/g` (see also remark in above update about usage first `*` or `+`)

```
var k,a,rg=/(<.*?>)|(\S+?(?=[\s<]))/g;

k='<html><div id="test"> it is interesting</div></html>';
a=k.match(rg);
console.log(a); // ["<html>", "<div id="test">", "it", "is", "interesting", "</div>", "</html>"]

k='<div class=\"Normal\" algoscore=\"338\">\n <p><img src=\"/getBinaryFile.php?Id=69\" /></p>\n';
a=k.match(rg);
console.log(a); // ["<div class="Normal" algoscore="338">", "<p>", "<img c="/getBinaryFile.php?Id=69" />", "</p>"]
```

Comment: bt I get blank spaces in between some location inside new array

Comment: Can you show real example string where you got _"blank spaces in between some location inside new array"_?

Comment: <div class=\"Normal\" algoscore=\"338\">\n <p><img src=\"/getBinaryFile.php?Id=69\" /></p>\n,

I think its the \n

Comment: Is there anyother method other than using regular expression, so that I can create a hash instead of array,

like
[
{"value" : "<html>" , "tag" : "html"},

{"value" : "<div id="test">" , "tag" : "html"},

{"value" : "it" , "tag" : "normal"},

{"value" : "is" , "tag" : "normal"},

.........

]

Comment: I think is better to convert array of strings from my answer into array of objects from your above example with usage next one line of code: `for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)a[i]={value:a[i],tag:/^</.test(a[i])?a[i].match(/^<(\S+?)[\s>]/)[1]:"normal"};`

Comment: Thanks... Im new to regular expressions. How do I split and symbols like coma and full stop to separate index...

Comment: I mean is it possible to split symbols like coma and full stop to separate index... for the above example

Comment: Yes, you can split string based on any criteria. You can search and learn how to use regular expression in javascript in web. Next link from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions